# Solutions within WSo2 ESB for Processing Zip files

Tags: wso2, esb

I have the following  requirement :
“Copy a Zip file from a sftp server to a directory on a local server, then unzip the file and extract 2 Xml files from inside it to process in our message service we have setup within our ESB.”

I have done some several searches over the past week on the internet, as well as read several topics in the Wso2 documentation but I cannot find a clean way to implement this requirement. I found this question asked on stackoverflow already - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806557/wso2-esb-extracting-and-processing-zip-files

However, I did not see where there were any suggestions/solutions provided. My first thought is to build a sequence with a class mediator to handle the extraction of the 2 xml files I need from the zip file, but maybe there is a better approach?

Is there any recommendations, links, or other references that folks could provide or suggest that would help me move forward with implementing this requirement? Or is this something I will need to handle outside of ESB via script with cron control?

Answer (score 1):

**Please kindly note that I'm assuming that you are using ESB 4.8.1**

Since this is a specific requirement we don't have an out of the box solution for your scenario. However, you can easily do this using WSO2's VFS transport and a custom class mediator. The procedure would be:

1. Read your zip file using [VFS Transport](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/VFS+Transport) and save it in your local server.
2. Next, create a class mediator which unzip your zip file and then read your XML files. For more details about how to write a class mediator please refer [Class Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Class+Mediator).

If you need more help regarding this issue please let me know.

Thanks,

Upul

Answer (score 1):

In the newer version of the ESB, the File Connector supports zip/unzip operations: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector+Version+2